# Delphi 7: combobox select where dbedit.text

Tags: delphi, combobox

i want to select a text from combobox delphi 7 by dbedit.text, is there any way to do it??

```
+-------------------------+
| `there's a combobox :`  | 
+-------------------------+
```

[image]   |

and this is `dbedit.text`

[image]

and i want to selected a combobox item by text in dbedit.text from mysql database ;

thanks master :)

Comment: `combobox.ItemIndex:=combobox.Items.IndexOf(dbedit.text)` is this what you ask?

Comment: yessssss. :D almost 2 hours just to find this, and almost give up. :( . thanks soooo mucch :)